# Filtering GridView with AJAX (ASP.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I'm looking to allow users to filter a GridView (with its contents coming from a datasource) by typing in text, and the GridView should refresh without a postback to display only rows where a certain column matches the text.

I think I know to do this by causing a postback, thus a reselect from the datasource, but is there an AJAX-y way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need AJAX.  http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a decent solution for this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26969/GridView-Multiple-Filter-AJAX-Control

Answer (score -1):

Can you use a different control, like the RadGridView?

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/filteringtemplatecolumns/defaultcs.aspx